# textfield placeholder centered and also change color

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I want to make my UITextField placeholder to `center aligned` and also change the `placeholderColor`.
I have already make text center aligned using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404725/center-align-placeholder-in-textfield) ↓

```
extension String {
    func attributedString(aligment: NSTextAlignment) -> NSAttributedString {
        return NSAttributedString(text: self, aligment: aligment)
    }
}

extension NSAttributedString {
    convenience init(text: String, aligment: NSTextAlignment) {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = aligment
        self.init(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
    }
}
```

and call above extension method like below

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(text: text, aligment: .left)
```

But I am not able to change the color of placeholder. How should I change my placeholder color? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Apply the foreground color attribute to your attributed string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using modified extension like below..

```
extension NSAttributedString 
    {
        convenience init(text: String, aligment: NSTextAlignment, color:UIColor) {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = aligment
            self.init(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:color])
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(text: text, aligment: .left, color:UIColor.red)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this code

Swift 3.0

```
myTextField.textAlignment = .center

myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "PlaceHolder", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green])
```

Comment: This is Swift 3 code, the question is tagged Swift 4.